# Jdeveloper : rebuild not supported during debug

Tags: debugging, jdeveloper

While I debug my application in Jdeveloper, at instances when I change an unit and try to rebuild it, changes don't reflect and I get the following error description:

"The debugger was unable to redefine the recompiled classes.
    Unsupported operation: changes to class modifiers."

Any suggestions?.

Comment: I think at some point classes can't be "refreshed" when changes occur. The same counts when changing method signatures. Small changes within he code of a method, e.g. a for-loop will be refreshed.

Comment: You may be right but sometimes even if I hadn't changed the code and rebuilt it..it threw the error. At that time I have to redeploy the application which looks frustrating.

Comment: Some informations about your app might be helpful: is it a web application, how is it packaged, etc?

Comment: Yes my application a fusion web application and I thought of it as a bug because same class can be changed after restarting the server and rebuild.